# Cannot access servlet despite changing URL to the servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I made a simple web app called "ServletContextExample" in which I access a servlet 
with a URL in an HTML page. The URL code was -

```
<a href = "/ServletContext/listenerTest.do">Click me</a>
```

Obviously, I get the `404 error` when I click this link. `ServletContext` should be changed
to `ServletContextExample`. Despite changing the code, rebuilding project, & republishing, restarting tomcat in Eclipse, I still get the 404 error. However, the Servlet can be
"accessed" by entering its url manually. How do I resolve this problem ?

```
404 error details - 

HTTP Status 404 - /ServletContext/listenerTest.do
The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: EDIT - Restarting eclipse solved the problem. But, I'd still like to know why this problem occurred in the first place ?

Comment: If this was JSP or Facelet instead of HTML, then you can append the [`HttpServletRequest#contextPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) to your URL. You can do it easily using expression language:

    `<a href="${request.contextPath}/listenerTest.do">Click me</a>`

Comment: What does `ServletContext` correspond to in this url? Why not just `listenerTest.do`?

Comment: @developerwjk - `ServletContext` is the name of my dynamic web project in eclipse. Earlier i was not using it in the url and was getting the 404 error all the time.